# Math function in android

Tags: android, function, math

I am trying to create a math function in android but I running into many problems.

First of all I don't know exactly how to declare it, my code:

```
double x;
double y = Math.abs(x) - Math.cos(x);
```

The function that I want to declare is `f(x)= x-cos(x)` but I am getting an error that x is not initialized but I wanna avoid typing `x = 0;` or something because later I wanna change the value of x.

Secondly I don't know how to call my function later to change it's value e.x f(y) or f(o) and `x` will be replaced by another number.

Comment: I am more worried about the second problem, so please focus there for starters

Answer (score 4):

You can't do that in Java. You have to wrap your function in a class/method like:

**Static**

```
public class MyFunction {

  public static double call(double x) {
     return Math.abs(x) - Math.cos(x);
  }
}

double result = MyFunction.call(4);
```

**Non static**

```
public class MyFunction {

  public double call(double x) {
     return Math.abs(x) - Math.cos(x);
  }
}

double result = new MyFunction().call(4);
```

Comment: Nice that works, although just so you know you have to make static the class MyFunction as well, at least in android.

Comment: You can make the method non static. In fact, I like more non-static version.

Comment: Dude, can you do extension methods like in c#? Like, define a function as `static T DoSomething(this string someString, int x)` and then you can call it like `string str = "hello world"; str.DoSomething(135);`? If so, he can definitely do it for double if he's going to frequently use double for mathematics, and I assume he would.

Comment: This is not possible in Java.

Answer (score 3):

You declare a function this way (forgive me if i mess up the syntax, i haven't done java in a while)

```
double calculate(double x) {
    return Math.abs(x) - Math.cos(x);
}
```

and later in your code, you can use it like this:

```
double num = 10.5;
double f = calculate(num);
```

and continue with whatever you need.
I would suggest watching basic java tutorials,
[this playlist](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLE7E8B7F4856C9B19) for example, or whatever fits your needs. If you're not familiar with the concept of functions, you need to have a look at all the basics of programming first.

Comment: Also, @bigdestroyer 's way of globalizing a function seems decent to me, regardless of defining the function itself. I don't do java much but I guess that there really isn't too much I don't know about defining functions.